# How to save HTML content in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have text area on my page. In that area I have to add some HTML code and save it to database. And it works for simple html, but when I select some text from "wikipedia" for example and paste it and try to save when SQL Query need to be executed I got exception with following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
The identifier that starts with '. Interestingly, old maps show the name as&nbsp;<em>Krakow</em>.</p>
<p>Kragujevac experienced a lot of historical turbulence, ' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
The identifier that starts with '>Paleolithic</a>&nbsp;era. Kragujevac was first mentioned in the medieval period as related to the public square built in a sett' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
The label 'http' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
The label 'http' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '>Belgrade Pashaluk</a>.</p>'
```

I am using asp mvc and razor engine. I don't know maybe I need to encome html somehow. I have also added this for ArticleText property:

```
[AllowHtml]        
        public string ArticleText { get; set; }
```

This is code for saving to database:

```
string sql = @"insert into tbl_articles 
                               (Text) values 
                               ("'" + article.ArticleText"'"+")";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The problem is that your ArticleText contains single quotes (aka apostrophes) that would need to be escaped. Why would you build dynamic SQL here instead of using a parameterized query?

Comment: Make a proc which does exactly what you have in your string and pass the HTML as a parameter... like magic.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Wow, **NO, NO, NO**. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and very bad stuff will happen if you don't use parametrized queries. So use parametrized queries.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("some conn string"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_articles (Text) values (@Text)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text", article.ArticleText);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Everytime you use the `+` operator to concatenate strings when building a SQL query you are doing something extremely dangerous and wrong.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, precisely, that's why I put them in `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I always use parametrized queries but I was building fast test and use this way to build query. So I thought that problem was somewhere else. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: and one more thing here, parametrized query saves you from SQL injection, but not from XSS, so use AntiXSS library, and sanitize the input before saving it. I am serious, do it ! :)

Comment: hey @DarinDimitrov can we same procedure follow in stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Try to save this way:

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_articles (Text) VALUES (@text)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, db.Connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@text", article.ArticleText);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of opening your system to a [Sql injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You need to escape the `'` character because if the Html contains the `'` character, it will break the SQL Statement when it is executed.

EDIT: Use Darins solution to solve the problem.

Comment: You need to do a lot more than just that to protect your system

Comment: seconded.  apostrophes are just the tip of the iceburg.

Comment: I sort of highlighted the very reason to the error at hand, the solution however is as you say more than just taking care of the `'`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string sql = @"insert into tbl_articles 
                               (Text) values 
                               (@articleText)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articleText",
                Server.HtmlEncode(article.articleText));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Why would you HtmlEncode it going into the database?  I think you'd want to do that coming out, not going in.

Comment: You need to DECODE when its going out.

Comment: ...so you want to HTMLEncode the text going into the database, then HtmlDecode the text coming out of the database?  To misquote a famous movie, "I do not think that means what you think it means."  You simply need to escape the text so it saves properly and safely into the database, not HtmlEncode it;  Likewise, as it is already HTML, you probably do not want to decode it when pulling it from the database.

Answer (score 1):

this should be parameterized:

```
    public void foo(string connectionString, string textToSave)
    {
        var cmdString = "insert into tbl_articles (text) values (@text)";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cmdString, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add("@text", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = textToSave;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

(this is the gereral idea, it's not completely functional as written.)